# ASP.NET MVC file encoding

Tags: asp.net-mvc, encoding

I first worked on a page with an external editor (simply Notepad++). Since the content is Italian, I set the enconding to UTF-8 and all the symbols I needed just worked.
The relevant parts are:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
[..]
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="it">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
[..]
```

When I opened those page in Visual Studio 2008 to start working on the real ASP.NET MVC application, the symbols I used (like `è` or `©`) do not work anymore but they're rendered in the browser like `Â©` and `Ã`.

In the editor they look correctly, by the way. Right clicking on the page on IE reveals that the encoding is correctly set to UTF-8.

Any help? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at "File / Advanced Save Options..." and see if there's anything dodgy there.

[Advanced Save Options http://i36.tinypic.com/inbfvt.png](http://i36.tinypic.com/inbfvt.png)